# Why should I need "Application-level" repeatable-reads?

Tags: sql, hibernate, transactions, isolation-level, optimistic-locking

In [Preventing lost updates in long conversations](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/) of the great blog of Vlad Mihalcea says that

> To prevent lost updates we must have **application-level repeatable
>   reads** along with a concurrency control mechanisms.

Why should I need "Application-level" repeteable read? Isn't enough with the concurrency control mechanism?

Note: I've written this in a Q&A style because reading the post made my doubt about the posibility of a stateless backend using Hibernate + Optimistic Locking. I've made my own conclusions (that explain answer my own question) but I can still making a mistake or omission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMHO** Exists three kinds of lost updates:

- Those that break consistency (this must be avoided 100%) and occur where two or more physical transactions modify the same data in a concurrent manner and exists race conditions.
- Those that break consistency (this must be avoided 100%) and occur where two logical transactions modify the same data.
- Those that occur during user think time (this should be avoided for a better user experience).

The first ones must be handled at database level and if we hadn't more than
the isolation levels in our toolbelt we definitely couldn't use READ_COMMITED. We should use at least REPETEABLE_READ to guarantee the data consistency.

If our RDBMS use Two Phase Locking (like SQL Server), the concurrency will suffer because the Shared Locks obtained in read querys will be released at the end (commit/rollback) of the transaction.

Instead, if our RDBMS use MVCC (like PostgreSQL) each query in a repeatable read transaction sees a snapshot as of the start of the first non-transaction-control statement in the transaction, and will only block a write operation if an Exclusive Lock has been taken, what means that another transaction is writing the same data, if this transaction succeds the one that is waiting must rollback (ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update).

The optimistic locking of Hibernate use the same approach that REPETEABLE_READ in PostgreSQL and both avoid correctly the lost update at the database level. 
The main difference is that REPETEABLE_READ can't take into account the user think time because it can't go further the boundaries of a pyshical transaction and typical web applications entail a read-modify-write conversational pattern that occur during multiple requests.

1. Alice requests a certain product for being displayed
2. The product is fetched from the database and returned to the browser
3. Alice requests a product modification
4. The product must be updated and saved to the database

In this conversation can happen that between 2 and 3 someone modify the product that Alice request at 1, and Alice wouldn't see that modification that will be overridden with the Alice request in 3.
[image]

This is presented like "The stateless conversation anti-pattern". Well I don't see it like that because that is the kind of lost update of type 2 that must be avoided with the validation rules of the domain (that aren't considered in the diagram).

Suppose the maximum stock of a product is 10.
The Alice request would be something like

```
POST /purchase
productId=1&quantity=3
```

Then the service that handles that request would do something like:

```
product = repository.retrieve(purchase.productId)
if (product.quantity + purchase.quantity <= 10)
  product.quantity = product.quantity + purchase.quantity
  repository.save(product)
  return Http.OK
else
  return Http.4XX
```

What it's still true is that Alice could be making a purchase based on old data.

1. Alice requests a certain product for being displayed
2. The product (quantity=5) is fetched from the database and returned to the browser
3. Bob post a purchase (purchase.quantity=2 so product.quantity now is 7)
4. Alice see product.quantity=5 and she wants that quantity=8 so makes a POST (purchase.quantity=3)
5. product.quantity=7 + purchase.quantity=3 <= 10 returns true so saves the product with quantity=10. This doesn't break business rules but will surprise Alice.

The problem is that in this scenario we are not considering user think time and the this allows lost updates of kind 3.
The solution here is push the optimistic locking into the application layer using a N_VERSION like Vlad says but he's not considering send the N_VERSION to the client and whitout that option we can have a stateless backend.
Even Hibernate [consider this option](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-optimistic-manual).
The scenario would be:

1. Alice requests a certain product for being displayed
2. The product (quantity=5, version=1) is fetched from the database and returned to the browser
3. Bob post a purchase (purchase.quantity=2 so product.quantity now is 7 and version=2)
4. Alice post a purchase (purchase.quantity=3)
5. Application version checking will throw a concurrency error ("Hey Alice, the product has been updated by another user")

One could say that the N_VERSION could be corrupted easily in a Javascript client (even I have [asked myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29973919/3517383)) but we will have the validation rules to maintain business invariants.

So I disagree with Vlad. I think we only need the business rules and the concurrency control mechanism: optimistic or pessimistic locking (although with pessimistic locking we couldn't avoid lost updates of type 3).

The benefit of application-level repeteable read as I see it is the use of extended session that maintains the objects between request, avoiding the need of refetch them in each request.

Answer (score 0):

In a [logical transaction](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/), you can have N physical transactions and N - 1 user think-times.

The user think-time is part of a logical transaction too, so basically you only have 1. and 2.

I fail to see how you can prevent the [lost update](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/) with domain model validations in the user think-time without [pessimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/) or optimistic locking.

With pessimistic locking, you can prevent the lost update but only in the last physical transaction but only if you consider the state that was loaded in that last transaction and not the one that was loaded in the beginning. That breaks the application-level repeatable-read guarantee.

Now, why would you need application-level repeatable-reads anyway?

And the answer is the same like in the isolation level repeatable-read case. With repeatable-reads you know that there's a serializable flow from read to write. Without this guarantee, you can allow the lost-update anomaly. The database transaction retains the same semantics too. Once an item is loaded, you can either prevent the lost update (2PL) or detect it (MVCCC). Application-level repeatable-reads do that too, but in the context of a multi-request logical transactions, hence you need to retain the same row value that you read and you need to enforce a locking mechanism. Since pessimistic locking would not scale 
across multiple requests, optimistic locking is the only viable locking mechanism to consider.

So, this approach is basically MVCC extrapolated to multiple requests.

Comment: "I fail to see how you can prevent the lost update with domain model validations in the user think-time without pessimistic locking or optimistic locking." Maybe I wasn't clear enough: It's true that the only way to prevent lost updates in the user think time is with optimistic locking (pessimistic will need the transaction alive for the entire logical transaction what is clearly an antipattern); but what I wanted to express is that it doesn't matter lose updates in user think time while we keep data consistent with our business rules.

Comment: However, I prefer to use READ_COMMITED with optimistic locking because 1. allows more concurrent transactions that REPETEABLE_READ in 2PL and 2. allows consider user think time that, altough it's not strictly necessary from the point of view of consistency, it is for the user experience

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but I think is beyond the topic of this question. read and write skew is true for the "stateful version-full conversation".

Comment: By the way, I though that read skew couldn't happen in any MVCC implementation of the REPETEABLE_READ. How can be avoided in PostreSQL like you list in your post. [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/transaction-iso.html) doesn't mean that when it says that:  _The Repeatable Read mode provides a rigorous guarantee that each transaction sees a completely stable view of the database. However, this view will not necessarily always be consistent with some serial (one at a time) execution of concurrent transactions of the same level._

Comment: _For example, even a read only transaction at this level may see a control record updated to show that a batch has been completed but not see one of the detail records which is logically part of the batch because it read an earlier revision of the control record. Attempts to enforce business rules by transactions running at this isolation level are not likely to work correctly without careful use of explicit locks to block conflicting transactions._

Comment: Postgresql repeatable read is actually Snapshot Isolation, which prevents read skew but not write skew. Serializable Snapshot Isolation prevents both.